How to interpret the matrix notation $\left[h_{i,j}\right]^K_{i,j=1}$?
I am reading a paper which defines a square matrix,
$$\textbf{H}=\left[h_{i,j}\right]^K_{i,j=1}\in \mathbb{C}^{K\times K},$$
where $i\in\left[1:K\right]$. I am trying to decipher this.  For example, if $K=2$ taking account of the superscript $K$ and subscript $j=1$, do I interpret this as,
$$\begin{pmatrix}h_{1,1} \\ h_{2,1}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}h_{1,1} & h_{2,1}\end{pmatrix}?$$

Square matrix should be $\pmatrix {h_{1,1}&h_{1,2}\h_{2,1}&h_{2,2}}$; $i$ and $j$ both run from $1$ to $K$, which is $2$ in this example

I think the $K$ superscript indicates the upper limit of the indices $i$ and $j$

@HVW "Valid" is down to taste but this is common notation. The $K$ represents an upper limit for $i$ AND $j$. The notation has the exact same meaning as
$$
[h_{i,j}]_{i,j = 1}^{K,K}
$$

I agree for $i$ as it was defined as $i\in\left[1:K\right]$.  But the subscript constrained $j$ to be $j=1$; that is what has confused me.
But the clairty from you both on $K$ is super helpful.

It’s like $\sum\limits_{i=1}^K\sum\limits_{j=1}^Kh_{i,j}$ could be abbreviated $\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^Kh_{i,j}$

Thanks @JW... appreciate your time :-)

Square matrix should be $\pmatrix {h_{1,1}&h_{1,2}\\h_{2,1}&h_{2,2}}$; $i$ and $j$ both run from $1$ to $K$, which is $2$ in this example.
